# C how to make it so that if something is not equal do this

Tags: c

I am wondering how to make it so that if lets say the variable A isnt equal to 1 and 2 do

> printf("Unknown letter type again\n");

thanks in advance if you know what to do and also is it possible if you type a letter to make you type a known letter

Comment: if (A != 1 || A != 2) { printf(...) }

Comment: You're kidding, right?

Comment: lol i tottaly forgot how to do that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (A !=1 || A!=2){
    printf(foobar);
}
```

After you changed your question, the answer would be...

```
if (A !=1 && A!=2) {
    printf(foobar);
}
```

Comment: `A` will always be not equal to at least one of `1` or `2`.  Did you mean to use logical AND - `&&` - instead?

Comment: Interesting. This is equivalent to `if (1) { ... }`. But that seems to be what the OP asked anyway.

Comment: @simonc per the OP, "A isnt equal to 1 or 2 do" the keyword being "or", I understand your point though

Comment: and now the original question has been edited... :P

Comment: thanks accidentally put or so i had to change it :P

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!((A == 1) || (A == 2)))
{
    printf("Unknown letter type again\n");
}
```

if A is not 1 or 2: print message

but if you are working with numbers in text/ASCII, you need to compare `A == '1'` instead of `A == 1`.

Comment: ahh nice, demorgans law :)

Comment: im just wotking with A actually being user input and not its numerical  code